# List insert iterator outside range (C++)

Tags: c++, std

I have a class `A` that can respond to `doSomething()` and some subclasses `B`, `C` and `D` that all override `doSomething()`. `B` particularly has an instance variable that is a list from the standard library and adds elements to such list when it responds to `doSomething()`.

In some part of my code, I create an array with pointers to objects of type `A`. Now,  If I declare it this way:

```
A* pointersToA[3];
pointersToA[0] = &B();
pointersToA[1] = &C();
pointersToA[2] = &D();
```

I get a `List insert iterator outside range` when calling `pointersToA[0]->doSomething()`.

But if I do it this way:

```
A* pointersToA[3];
B b = B();
pointersToA[0] = &b;
pointersToA[1] = &C();
pointersToA[2] = &D();
```

Everything works as expected.

Why does this happen?

Comment: I'm sorry but [your code doesn't compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/938cc4dc9617aa62) so I'm curious as to how you manage to get a runtime error out of it.

Comment: @Borgleader Now it should - sorry about that.

Comment: A good compiler will warn about this - "taking the address of a temporary" or something along those lines. It's good to enable as many warnings as possible (and not ignore them).

Comment: @molbdnilo: A good compiler will not compile this at all :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you do this:

```
pointersToA[0] = &B();
```

you are storing a pointer to a temporary in `pointersToA[0]`. This is invalid in standard C++, and a conforming implementation should emit an error. The fact that this compiler for you suggests your compiler has either  a bug or a non-standard extension.

Given that your compiler accepts that code, the issue is that after that line, `pointersToA[0]` is invalidated because the `B` object it points to no longer exists. De-referencing that pointer is *undefined behaviour*.

When you do this

```
B b = B();
pointersToA[0] = &b;
```

you store a pointer to object b. As long as b is alive, it is OK to access it via `pointersToA[0]`.

---

***Note:*** It would be a good idea to disable this "extension" in your compiler to avoid running into this kind of problem.

Answer (score 6):

Taking an address of an rvalue is pretty much guaranteed to cause problems sooner or later (typically sooner), and is actually illegal in C++ (so your compiler isn't exactly top-notch on that). An address isn't a *strong* reference to an object; since C++ is not a garbage-collected language, the values of `B`, `C` and `D` disappear as soon as the statements they are used in are executed.

For your use dynamic allocation sounds like the most straighforward way:

```
std::array<std::unique_ptr<A>, 3> pointersToA {
    std::make_unique<B>(),
    std::make_unique<C>(),
    std::make_unique<D>()
};
```

Comment: I think it's worth showing the **bad** solution to the OPs code would be to just use raw pointers, so `&B()` becomes `new B()`. However, this leads to terrible manual memory management. The code here is a 'perfect' solution as memory is automatically managed.

Comment: @Walter The question was marked C++, and that implies C++14, because that's the latest C++ standard at the time of writing.

Comment: Either way, it's trivial to just roll your own version.

Answer (score 1):

```
pointersToA[0] = &B();
```

This creates a temporary object, calls its constructor, stores a pointer to the object in pointersToA[0], then the temporary object gets destroyed, invoking its destructor. From this point, the stored pointer in  pointersToA[] is no longer valid, and using it is undefined behavior.

```
B b = B();
pointersToA[0] = &b;
```

Here, the object continues to exist, until the end of this scope, and using this pointer, dereferencing it, calling its method, is a valid operation, until the end of the scope, and the object gets destroyed.

The error message you were getting is due to undefined behavior. "Undefined behavior" means anything: the code still runs, produces the correct result; or the code still runs, produces garbage results; or the code fails with some random error; or your entire computer catches fire, and explodes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a pointer and store it, you will need a smart pointer class or new. What you are actually doing is creating a temporary object, and then storing the pointer to where it used to be, so when you call b::doSomething(), you are calling an already destructed object.

```
#include <iostream>
class base {};
class derived : public base {
public:
    derived() { std::cout << "constructed" << std::endl;}
    ~derived() { std::cout << "destructed" << std::endl;}
};

int main(){
    base *pointers[3];
    pointers[0] = &derived();
    std::cout << "pointer assigned" << std::endl;
    return 0;
};
```

output:

```
constructed
destructed
pointer assigned
```